# Problem using ProgressDialog with onCreateDialog / onPrepareDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm using the following code to create a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) (inside my [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)):

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOOKUP:
            return new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOOKUP:
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialogLookup_title);
            ((ProgressDialog)dialog).setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialogLookup_message));
            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it isn't actually setting the title and is putting it in some weird double-box.

It's giving me this:

[image: bad progress]

but I'm expecting something more like this:

[image: good progress]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your onPrepareDialog a method on a subclass of Dialog?

Comment: No. As I said, they're in the Activity:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried your sample and it seems changing from `ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER` to `ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL` fixed the weird double-box problem.

And it also displays the title and text.

Edit:

You are passing `ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER` in the `ProgressDialog` constructor.

From the doc, the 2nd argument is a theme id.

You will have to create a `ProgressDialog` object and use the `setProgressStyle` to `ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER`

```
case DIALOG_LOOKUP:
     ProgressDialog pdlg = new ProgressDialog(this);
     pdlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
     return pdlg;
```

Comment: D'oh... how could I have missed that? I'm still not getting a title though.

Comment: Well, for some reason I had to move my `setTitle()` into `onCreateDialog()`, but that seems to have done it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It was a long time ago, but in case it helps anyone: I found that that dialog.setTitle(...) only works in the onPrepareDialog() if it is also set in the onCreateDialog(). (tried it on 4.1.2)